# How to validate Jmeter JSON response against Database data

Tags: java, arrays, json, jmeter, assertion

I'm searching for a solution how to assert Jmeter JSON response against Database data and print discrepancies in Assertion result message

**Jmeter JSON response example**

```
{"data": [
        {
        "code": 99,
        "name": "A"
    },
        {
        "code": 2,
        "name": "B"
    },
        {
        "code": 7,
        "name": "C"
    },
        {
        "code": 4,
        "name": "D"
    },
        {
        "code": 6,
        "name": "E"
    },
        {
        "code": 3,
        "name": "C"
    }
]}
```

**Database data as fetched through JDBC Sampler as JSON**

```
[
        {
        "name": "A",
        "code": 1
    },
        {
        "name": "B",
        "code": 2
    },
        {
        "name": "F",
        "code": 7
    },
        {
        "name": "D",
        "code": 4
    },
        {
        "name": "E",
        "code": 6
    },
        {
        "name": "C",
        "code": 3
    }
]
```

**Assertion message example**

```
        Discrepancies 
     API                          DB
{"code": 99,"name": "a"} <->    {"name": "A","code": 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using JSR223 Assertion?

Refer https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial/

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming what you have above JSON values saved into `fromJSON` and `fromDatabase` [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) correspondingly

1. Add [JSR223 Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion) as a child of the [Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) you want to fail
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def fromJSON = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(vars.get('fromJSON'))
   def fromDatabase = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(data: new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(vars.get('fromDatabase'))).toPrettyString())


   def differences = fromJSON.collectEntries { k, v -> fromDatabase[k] ? [k, (v - fromDatabase[k])] : [:] }

   if (differences.data.size() != 0) {
       AssertionResult.setFailure(true)
       AssertionResult.setFailureMessage('Discrepancies : ' + System.getProperty('line.separator')
               + new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(differences).toPrettyString())
   }
   ```
3. That's it, in case of mismatches the assertion will generate Sampler failure and report the differences:

   [image]

You might also be interested in alternative approaches which require less coding and Groovy knowledge, for example [Jackson](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-compare-two-json-objects) or [JSONAssert](https://github.com/skyscreamer/JSONassert), check out [The Easiest Way To Compare REST API Responses Using JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-easiest-way-to-compare-rest-api-responses-using-jmeter/) article for more details.